# Show the Beta function $B(x,y)=\int_{0}^{1}t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}dt$ is defined for $x,y > 0$ without actually integrating

Tags: calculus, integration

An old exam question: Show that 
$$B(x,y)=\int_{0}^{1}t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}dt$$ exists for all $x,y>0$.

I'm sure because of time allotment that it's not in the scope of the question to actually integrate.

Is there an elegant way to show that the integral exists without calculating it explicitely?

Comment: Can you show $\int_0^1t^{x-1}~\mathrm dt$ converges for all $x>0$?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I'm afraid I don't know how...

Comment: You don't know how to integrate $t^{x-1}$?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Oh god sorry of course I do its $\frac{1}{x}t^x$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Insert edit: But I'm afraid I don't know how that _helps_ :)

Comment: Can you show $\int_0^1(1-t)^{y-1}~\mathrm dt$ converges for all $y>0$? Can you show that $(1-t)^{y-1}$ is bounded for $t\in[0,0.5]$ and $t^{x-1}$ is bounded for $t\in[0.5,1]$?

Comment: I do not understand what you need. Proof that it converge without integrate: a) To know the existence of a similar integral that has a known value; or b) 0<=f(t)<=1 f(t) continuous then integrable on [0,1]

Or you need to know what is the formula?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Ok, so the integral convergence is obvious as we can just integrate. $t^{x-1}$ is bounded above by two and below by zero. Same logic for $(1-t)^{y-1}$ as $(t-1)\in [0.5,1]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

It is easy to just integrate $t^{x-1}$ for $x>0$, and since $(1-t)^{y-1}\approx 1$ in a neighborhood of $t=0$, the integral converges near $t=0$.

Likewise, the same holds for $t=1$ and $(1-t)^{y-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, write $$B(x,y)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{t^{1-x}(1-t)^{1-y}}$$ is an improper integral it will be definedconvergent (real and finite), if $1-x<1$ and $1-y<1 \Rightarrow x, y>0.$

Like $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}} =2,~~ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{dt}{(1-t)^{1/3}}=3/4, ~ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t(1-t}}=\pi $$

Recurrence relations 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function
like $B(x+1,y ) = B(x,y) \frac{x}{x+y}, B(x,y+1) = B(x,y) \frac{y}{x+y}, B(x,y)= B(x+1,y)+B(x,y+1)$, $B(1,x)=\frac{1}{x}, B(1,1-x) = \frac{\pi}{\sin \pi x}$

can be helpful if one does not want to compute them by integration or by the well known formula.

Comment: I think I see what you're trying to do, is there a way to formalize that result? I fear examples will be enough for the prof. ;)

Comment: #@Ruben Kruepper I have added some more stuff, you may see it now.

Answer (score -3):

$\frac{\Gamma{(\alpha+\beta)}}{\Gamma{(\alpha)}\Gamma{(\beta)}}t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}$ is the Beta density and the area under the curve is 1

Then $\int_{0}^{1}t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}dt=\frac{\Gamma{(\alpha)}\Gamma{(\beta)}}{\Gamma{(\alpha+\beta)}}$